# How do I use the og.likes action type be used with the product object type?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Can the `og.likes` action type be used with the `product` object type?

Using this code:

```
let properties = [
    "og:type": "product",
    "og:title": "Test Product",
    "og:description": "Product description"
]

let object = FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject(properties: properties)

let action = FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction()
action.actionType = "og.likes"
action.setObject(object, forKey: "product")

let content = FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent()
content.action = action
content.previewPropertyName = "product"

FBSDKShareDialog.show(from: self, with: content, delegate: nil)
```

I get the error:

> “Action Requires At Least One Reference: The action you’re trying to publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects. At least one of the following properties must be specified: object.

If I replace `product` with `object` it works, but I don't want to use the generic object.

Comment: The parameter name has to be `object`. This is not about the OG meta data.

Comment: Sorry, are you talking about the previewPropertyName?

Comment: The parameter name under which you pass the URL of the Open Graph object to like, must be `object`. I don’t know how exactly that translates into swift, but check the code example in the documentation, that should make it clear.

Comment: Hi, I am currently dealing with exactly the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry, I've moved onto working on other things at the moment and hadn't found a solution so far. I may return to this at some point, but if you work it out first, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

The key of parameters for "og.likes" action type just name "object"
[Screenshot from Facebook Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63Fqr.png)